# Simple MySQL join

Tags: mysql

This works fine for player1name but how do I solve player2name?

While I'm at it, let me know if you know any useful visual query builders ;)

```
SELECT 
_game.player1,
_user.username AS player1name,
_game.player2,
_user.username AS player2name,
FROM _game
LEFT JOIN _user ON _game.player1 = _user.id
```

Comment: Btw, player1 and player2 is just a playerId

Comment: why is player1name and player2name referencing the same _user.username column? and where did "_headsup" come from?

Comment: Because I don't want to store the user/playername in the game table. So _user.username contains every players name.

Comment: Just edited to clear things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have mySQL running ATM, but it should be something like...

```
SELECT 
player1,
u1.username AS player1name,
 player2,
u2.username AS player2name,
FROM _game
INNER JOIN _user u1 ON _headsup.player1 = u1.id
INNER JOIN _user u2 ON _headsup.player2 = u2.id
```

i.e. alias on the join, use the alias in the select.

However, I'm at a loss as to where _headsup comes from!

Comment: This looks good but without the parentheses or GROUP BY I get 16 duplicates. Anyways, INNER JOIN was perfectly suited in this case.

Comment: It sounds like this is a fragment of SQL, so almost certainly a join or where clause is missing that's allowing for duplicates to slip through the net.

Comment: Don't know exactly what happened but the table had 2 rows and when I copied this example I got 18 rows.

Comment: _headsup isn't joined to _game (well _game isn't joined to anything!), unless there is a fragment missing in your example, this could be the problem

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT player1,
_user.username AS player1name,
 player2,
_user2.username AS player2name
FROM _game
LEFT JOIN _user ON (_headsup.player1 = _user.id)
LEFT JOIN _user _user2 ON (_headsup.player2 = _user2.id)
```

Comment: Sorry, I deleted the comma before the FROM.

Comment: LEFT JOIN _user2 doesn't exist. Alias _user u2 would be correct ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
   player1,
   usr1.username AS player1name,
   player2,
   usr2.username AS player2name,
FROM _game
LEFT JOIN _user usr1 ON usr1.id= _game.player1
LEFT JOIN _user usr2 ON usr2.id= _game.player2
```

Comment: i don't know why you have _headsup.player1 since it's not part of the tables mentioned in the query

Answer (score 0):

When you join `_game` ON `_user`, I think you have to specify which fields to join by *on those two tables*. You specify that join, but then try to join `_headsup` and `_user`.

Not sure what `player1` and `player2` are, but those might come up as ambiguous fields since you did not say which table they are from.

So join `_game` on `_user` first, then make a second join with `_user` on `_headsup`

```
FROM _game
LEFT JOIN _user ON _game.someField = _user.someField
JOIN _headsup ON _user.id = _headsup.player1
```

Comment: This would probably also work but I think it looks cleaner with 2 inner joins. Pros and cons regarding the performance?

Comment: I did left join because you did left join. I left the second open to do whatever kind of join you need to do. It only depends on what you need the query to do.